# Why does `has_one` in rails require a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Consider two tables `Foo` and `Bar` and consider models based on them. Now consider a one-to-one relationship between them.

`Foo` contains `has_one :bar` in it's declaration so that we're able to access `Bar` from `Foo`'s objects. But then what I don't understand is why `Bar` needs a foreign key referencing `Foo`?

Shouldn't it be easier if they just compare both the `id`s to get the result?

I'm assuming that there will be problems with comparing both `id`s and I want to know what the problems are.

Comment: this should help https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with ids is that they store auto-incremented values. Let's consider 2 tables `students` and `projects`. 
Let's assume a student can have at most 1 project. Which means he can either have a project or not.

Now consider 2 students A & B.

`students table`

```
id name
1   A
2   B
```

now `projects table`

```
id name
1  P1
2  NULL
```

in this case A has a project named as P1 but B doesn't and we're creating a null entry just to maintain and match the id of records present in projects with the students but this is not feasible in the long term. If in a school there are 1000 students then we'll have may be 500 empty rows for 500 students who are not working on a project.

That's why adding a column in `projects table` is a feasible solution to reduce the size of the table and maintain relationships as well and also if you're going to delete a record then the new id won't be same as the previous one as id's are auto-incremented.

now `projects table`

```
id name student_id
1  P1    1
```

is more feasible and flexible as well. You can make it has_many as well because a student can work on multiple projects as well.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume that the DB engine will add the same IDs to rows in different tables. You can (I would not recommend) make an app with such behavior and implement it with triggers and constraints, but this would be a very creative (in a negative sense) approach to relational databases.